# How to preserve and load between different forms WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Buttons to different Forms]

I have created different Forms which display in my main panel on click.

```
private void ButtonECM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panelDesktop.Controls.Clear();
    FrmECM FrmECM_Vrb = new FrmECM() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
    FrmECM_Vrb.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.panelDesktop.Controls.Add(FrmECM_Vrb);
    FrmECM_Vrb.Show();
}
```

This creates one instance of a Form.

PROBLEM: When I switch between different Forms (over the click event), it always creates a new Instance and the things I type into the form and work with are gone.

Can I check somehow that the Form is already loaded and switch back to it unchanged?

Comment: you may hide instead closing(event Closing + cancel close) and then reuse instance ... (of course you also have to had special method to (or field to indicate) really close the form when you close main form)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are clearing all instances of the forms when this event is fired. Instead of clearing all instances, hide the form using the .Hide() method on your form control. Then call the .Show() method to display the form again.

MS .Hide docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.hide?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

MS .Show docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-show